# How to sum from 3 columns

Tags: sql-server

I'm new to Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and I am stumped on this one homework question. I am trying to get a final total of 3 columns (Upkeep, Staging and Marketing by Housing Type) as a new column on the right (next to Marketing column). Please refer to this [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykGvU.png) for the image of what I mean.

Thanks! Hope you guys can help!!!

Comment: Why can you not put up a + between three columns before formatting.

Comment: yes that worked..! thanks!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps I'm not understanding the question, but it seems you just need to add the three sums together and then format.  Example below.

```
select format( (sum([Upkeep]) 
+ sum([Staging]) 
+ sum([Marketing])), 'c') as 'Total'
from Market.dbo.Data
Group by Housing
```